# How to Create Indefinite Duration for a Task in Windows 2003 Task Scheduler

Tags: c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks, windows-2003-webserver

I'm trying to create tasks with an indefinite duration. On Windows Server 2008, if I don't specify the duration, then the duration is assumed infinite. However, on Windows Server 2003 a duration must be specified (and be equal or greater than the interval). Currently, I am just setting the task to have a duration of a year if it is meant to repeat a long time.

**Is there a way to specify an indefinite duration on Windows Server 2003?**

```
if (m_TimeInterval.m_Expire.Year < 2099) //xp and win7 max year is 2099
    tTrigger.Repetition.Duration = m_TimeInterval.getDuration();
else if (!newVer) tTrigger.Repetition.Duration = m_TimeInterval.getInterval().Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
tTrigger.Repetition.Interval = m_TimeInterval.getInterval();
tTrigger.Repetition.StopAtDurationEnd = true;
```

Notes:

- I am using the Task Scheduler API to add these task definitions.
- Interval and Duration are set by use of TimeSpans.
- `newVer` is false since I am working with Task Scheduler 1.1 and not 1.2 or higher
- `tTrigger` is of type TimeTrigger

Comment: What about creating a separate Schedule Task whose sole purpose is to stop and restart the task you want to have an indefinite duration, effectively resetting the duration?

Comment: That is a possible work-around, thanks. Although, stopping and starting the task would not update the original timespan of a year defined, so it would have to delete and recreate the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using 1-1-2099 as 'indefinite'

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `TimeSpan.Zero` which makes the task infinite.

Heres a short code snippet to demonstrate how to use it on a Trigger :

```
Trigger triggerTask = Trigger.CreateTrigger(TaskTriggerType.Time);
triggerTask.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
triggerTask.SetRepetition(new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0, 0, 0), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Duration.Forever.TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.duration.forever.aspx)?

Comment: The description is right on the money, but it looks like that's a WPF base element class. Services are essentially console applications.