# How to change WindowTaskScheduler RunDurationFor to Indefinitely

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6.2

I have the method below to create TaskScheduler for Windows using [ASquare.WindowsTaskScheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ASquare.WindowsTaskScheduler/), and it works as expected.

```
public bool CreateTaskScheduler()
{
    var file = $"{Setting.GetDirectory()}\\{Setting.GetSpacename()}.exe";
    var response = WindowTaskScheduler
        .Configure()
        .CreateTask(TaskName, file)
        .RunDaily()
        .RunEveryXMinutes(5)
        .Execute();
    if (response?.ErrorMessage != null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(response?.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return response != null && response.IsSuccess;
}
```

Now the requirement has changed and I need to change the Duration time to Indefinitely.

So I tried to add the following line to the code:

```
.RunDurationFor(TimeSpan.MaxValue)
```

It works but the max time was 168 minutes, I searched a bit and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742880/how-to-create-indefinite-duration-for-a-task-in-windows-2003-task-scheduler) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327999/timeout-infinitetimespan-in-net-4-0) tried to change `TimeSpan` inside `.RunDurationFor` following:

try 1 `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, -1)`

try 2 `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, Timeout.Infinite)`

try 3 `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)`

try 4 `new TimeSpan(0, 23, 0, 0, 0)`

When I run the code only try 4 create a task Task Scheduler for 23 hours. But try 1, 2, and 3 do not return any exceptions but do not create the Task Scheduler.

My question is, any idea how to write inside `RunDurationFor(//what to write here)` so it can be valid for creating an Indefinitely?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The following may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742880/how-to-create-indefinite-duration-for-a-task-in-windows-2003-task-scheduler

Comment: Have you tried 0?

Comment: I was thinking TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0),.  Like you were thinking 0 and -1 are often used as infinite.

Comment: Did not helped @Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many hours of trial and fail. I assume ASquare.WindowsTaskScheduler has a bug or not updated. Of course, if someone finds a solution to ASquare I would still appropriate an answer, but till that comes, here is my alternative solution:

I have installed [TaskScheduler 2.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/) NuGet package and it works as I wanted with the following code:

```
public void CreateTaskScheduler()
{
    var file = $"{Setting.GetDirectory()}\\{Setting.GetSpacename()}.exe";
    TaskService ts = new TaskService();
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    Trigger trigger = new DailyTrigger();
    trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    td.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(file, null, null));
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(TaskName, td);
}
```

So `Indefinitely` duration is default by this code.

Here is a snapshot of the results I wanted:

[image]

Hope that helps.